# Unreconized import path when imported package has another dependency

Tags: windows, go, import, compiler-errors

I have this folder/file structure:

```
src (folder)
L site.app (folder)  
  L hello (folder)  
    L hello.go  
    L hello.mod  
  L packagea (folder) 
    L packagea.go  
    L packagea.mod
  L packageb (folder)  
    L packageb.go
    L packageb.mod
```

In my hello.mod

```
replace site.app/packagea => ../packagea
require (
    site.app/packagea v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
)
```

In my packagea.mod

```
replace site.app/packageb => ../packageb
require (
    site.app/packageb v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
)
```

When I build the packagea it there is no error,
but when I tried to build the hello this error shows

```
go: site.app/packagea@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000 requires
        site.app/packageb@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000: unrecognized import path "site.app/packageb": https fetch: Get "https://site.app/packageb?go-get=1": EOF
```

The main is in the hello.go

Comment: is this a single project? Where is main in this directory structure?

Comment: Yes this is a single project & I want to modularize it. The main is in the hello.go

Comment: Normally I keep a single mod file per project; Now what is happening is your when you build application looks for package b and is not able to find it